# How to implement media session to support Google assistant

Tags: android, exoplayer, mediasession

We are trying to implement media session in our video Android TV App to support Google Assistant voice control.

On emulator, we can successfully send play, pause, fast-forward command to control Youtube playback, but when we try the official ClassicsKotlin project (https://github.com/android/tv-samples/tree/main/ClassicsKotlin), it only responds to play and pause command, when we issue fast-forward command, Google assistant will respond "Sorry, I can not do this on this App".

Afaik, ClassicsKotlin uses Exoplayer, and Exoplayer's MediaSessionConnector does implement the media session logic, but why it does not work?

How to implement media session correctly to support Google Assistant?